# Prevent fontawesome icon in a Bootstrap button to wrap to next line alone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, line-breaks

Here is a simple Bootstrap 4 button with a fontawesome icon. When the button is placed in a container that is *a bit* smaller than its natural width, the icon is pushed to the next line.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="#" class="btn btn-light">One two three <i class="fa fa-arrow-right ml-1"></i></a>

<p class="mt-2">
  When in a smaller container / window size:
</p>

<div class="mt-2" style="width: 140px;">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">One two three <i class="fa fa-arrow-right ml-1"></i></a>
</div>
```

Is there any way that I could prevent the icon to go to the next line alone (as shown below)? That is to force the last word to wrap to the next line **with** the icon.

[image]

I know I could wrap the last word and the icon within a span with `white-space: nowrap;` as shown below:

`<span style="white-space: nowrap;">three <i class="fa fa-arrow-right ml-1"></i></span>`

But this isn't a viable solution in my case. Is there a pure CSS way to achieve that? Placing a `&nbsp;` between the last word and the icon doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a pure CSS way to achieve that?

I honestly doubt it.

Best I can think of is a JS crutch along the lines of this

```js
document.querySelectorAll("i.fa-arrow-right").forEach(function (self) {
  var parent = self.parentNode;
  var words = self.previousSibling.nodeValue.split(/(?<=\s)/);
  var nobr = document.createElement("NOBR");

  parent.removeChild(self.previousSibling);
  parent.insertBefore(nobr, self);
  nobr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words.pop()));
  nobr.appendChild(self);
  parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(words.join('')), nobr);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-light">One two three <i class="fa fa-arrow-right ml-1"></i></a>

<p class="mt-2">
  When in a smaller container / window size:
</p>

<div class="mt-2" style="width: 140px;">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">One two three <i class="fa fa-arrow-right ml-1"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the snippet. That does the trick although I was hoping for a CSS solution but I also doubt there is one... I will give this a try!